# How to make text of anchor tag to appear in center when the li element is circular

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a horizontal navigation menu , My menu items (li) elements are in shape of circle here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Az8cG/) , my question is the text of the link is appearing on top , how do I make it to appear on center , will that be possible , please let me know that , any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only block items can use margins and padding. Anchor tags are inline elements. You need to force them to be block elements in your CSS:

```
#menu ul li a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    padding:30px 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: great worked for me thanks , another question , on hover of my li element , i want to change its background-color , I tried but it didnt work.thanks

Comment: this is partially wrong, not only block elements can have a margin and padding applied to them, but with a different behaviour compared to block elements e.g. on inline elements, left/right padding and margin gets rendered but it doesn't happen the same for top/bottom ones.

Answer (score 1):

And if text flows over 2 lines, you can use this to keep it in the middle:

```
#menu ul li a
{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:85px;
    width:35px;
}
```

And the answer to your second question:

```
#menu ul li:hover
{
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , but the second answer didnot help , could you try in the demo I provided.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question posted in response to Diodeus:

If you want to use pure css3 hover effect, you'll want to do something similar to this by using the :hover selector:

```
#menu ul li a:hover {
   background-color: #000000;
   }
```

For nice effects, use the CSS3 transition property which you can see here:

http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

Answer (score 1):

Rather than messing with vertical align, set the line-height equal to the height/width of the circle.

Your issue with the red background not taking was that the specificity of the selector it was declared in: `li:hover` was not high enough to overcome the original bg color declaration in `#menu ul li`.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Az8cG/11/ for both fixes.

Answer (score 1):

I just played with your fiddle. What i did is just made "li" display:inline-block & changed li:hover to #menu li:hover.

```
#menu ul li
{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:40px 30px;
    background-color:slategray;
    margin:0 20px 0 0;
    height:17px;
   -webkit-border-radius:50px;
}
#menu li:hover
{
   -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 50px 12px #69CDF5;
  background:#cb2326;  
}
```

Please check the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Az8cG/15/